# Matrix that maps all points on R^3 on to a line

Tags: linear-algebra

Give a 3x3 matrix that maps all points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto the line $[x,y,z] = t[a,b,c]$ and does not move the points that are on that line. Prove your matrix has these properties.

I'm not sure how to start this problem. My instructor told me the matrix should have a rank of 1, but I don't know what I should do with that hint. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Hint: the rank of a matrix is the dimension of it's image (if we interpret the matrix as a linear map)

Answer (score 1):

Look at it as a linear transformation, say $T$. Consider the dimension of the range of $T$,clearly equal the given line, spanned by the directional, so dimension $1$. Remember that the dimension of image of $T$ equals rank of $T$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: If it has rank 1, it consists of 1 vector with 2 other vectors dependent on it; these are necessarily multiples of each other and implies WHAT?